# QT получение данных по сокету в цикле

Tags: c++, qt, сокет

я по сокету получаю структуру, которая постоянно обновляется. Нижеописанным способом мне удалось корректно вывести значения, отправляемые в первый раз. Но не пойму, как дальше выводить обновленные данные. К примеру в цикле на 5 повторений данные структуры после первого прохода уже не соответствуют пересылаемым значениям. Подозреваю, что нужно очищать структуру или переменную array после вывода первых значений. Также проверять в цикле while наличие новых данных в переменной array, и при их наличии уже передавать в структуру и выводить.

```
struct Message {
    float latitude; //широта
    float longitude; //долгота
} __attribute__((packed));


for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
QByteArray array;
array = clientSocket->readAll();
Message* m = reinterpret_cast<Message*>(array.data());
qDebug() << m->latitude << "latitude";
qDebug() << m->longitude << "longitude";
}
```

Comment: Читайте из сокета данные порциями по размеру структуры. А перед этим еще добавить проверку, что данных для вычитывания достаточно (`>= sizeof(Message)`).

Comment: @user207200 Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью readAll может передаваться не одна структура, а данные сразу нескольких. Из-за чего в переменной array у меня данных больше чем для одной структуры?

Comment: Именно так. А может быть, что их там меньше, чем на 1 структуру или вообще 0.

Comment: цикл это идеологически не правильно, надо использовать сигнал `readyRead()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас структура занимает 8 байт, и если вы прочитали из сокета 8 байт, то вам повезло и в вашем 'array' лежит эти самые 8 байт, и следовательно эта строка `Message* m = reinterpret_cast<Message*>(array.data())` даст ожидаемый результат. Но вот далеко на факт что `readAll` вернет то что вы отправили.

Во-первых вы постоянно читаете из сокета и если там ничего нет (еще ничего не успело прийти) `array` все равно будет пустым, а вы его кастуете к `Message`. Там получается грязь, хотя должен падать, т.к. Если размер `array` меньше 8 байт, вот здесь `Message* m = reinterpret_cast<Message*>(array.data())` вы залезете не в ту область памяти.

Решение - читать именно столько сколько вам нужно - 8 байт. Используйте например `readData`, или используйте `readAll`, но вычленяйте нужные вам 8 байт.